# Math Symbols fonts like Gigi fonts in Microsoft windows

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols

I want to get the font in mathmode like Gigi in Microsoft windows as follow:

[image]

In LaTeX math fonts,  I  find out that  I  use  `\mathscr{S}` (`mathrsfs` package) like 
the code is

```
%\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\[\mathscr{S} = \sum_i^n a_i\]
```

get the fonts:

[image]

It is not very good, My question is that how to get it better by a new command or package, something else and so on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font that comes closest to your example, and has TeX support is probably  Adobe Bickham Script Pro, but it is a commercial font, and quite expensive. To look for other alternatives you may consult the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalfa/mathalfa.pdf) of the `mathalfa` package.

Comment: Thx, I read it.